# How can I bifurcated address component wise which I am getting directly from Google Place API?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I want to get the city, state, country, pin into a different variable like as I am getting the address, lat, and longitude. But I don't know how can I get address component-wise.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String TAG = "placeautocomplete";
String API = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
String Latitude;
String Longitude;
double lat, lng;
String Address,Place_name,Phone,Complete_address;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edit = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    txtView = findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    // Initialize Places.
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), API);
    // Create a new Places client instance.
    PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
    if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), API);


    }

    // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
    AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

    assert autocompleteFragment != null;

    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.ADDRESS,Place.Field.PHONE_NUMBER));
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());

            if (place.getLatLng() !=null){
                lat =place.getLatLng().latitude;
                lng =place.getLatLng().longitude;

            }
            Latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
            Longitude= String.valueOf(lng);
            Address= place.getAddress();
            Place_name = place.getName();
            Phone = place.getPhoneNumber();

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}
 }
```

I just want to address in components like Address, City, State, Pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use not `Address= place.getAddress()` but `.getAddressComponents()` for do that, because [`.getAddress()`](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/model/Place.html#getAddress()) returns `String` with human-readable address of place and in Official Documentation Google wrote:

> Do not parse the formatted address programmatically. Instead you
>   should use the individual address components, which the API response
>   includes in addition to the formatted address field.

So, you should use [`Place.getAddressComponents()`](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/model/Place.html#getAddressComponents()) to get `List<AddressComponent>` and than get name and [type of each address component](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types#table2). Or use additional request for place lat/lng and [`Geocoder.getFromLocation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) like in [Display a location address](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address#java) Official Example:

```
...
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = null;

...
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
            Latitude,    // <-- your Latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
            Longitude,   // <- your Longitude= String.valueOf(lng);
            location.getLongitude(),
            // In this sample, get just a single address.
            1);

// Handle case where no address was found.
if (addresses == null || addresses.size()  == 0) {
    if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
        errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
    }
    deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
} else {
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Fetch the address lines using getAddressLine,
    // join them, and send them to the thread.
    for(int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
        addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
    }
}
...
```

Also take a look at [Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types).

P.S.  Do not use capitalized names (for example, `Latitude`) for variables - this is the style for classes. Name it just `latitude`.

Comment: @TARUNSHARMA Use `place.getAddressComponents()`  to get address parts and combine them as you wish.

Comment: How can I use place.getAddressComponents() can you refer me any example? I could not find in the documentation.

Comment: @TARUNSHARMA I'm try, and seems you can do that only via additional Geocoder request: `geocoder.getFromLocation()` - with Latitue and Longitude from your `onPlaceSelected()` response.

Comment: I checked the latest documentation but can not find. https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: @TARUNSHARMA You don't need any migration docs for [`Geocoder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200163/discussion-between-tarun-sharma-and-andrii-omelchenko).

Comment: Sir can you help me I Stuck in another google map related problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165815/how-can-i-calculate-distance-between-multiple-latitude-and-longitude/58165869?noredirect=1#comment102713909_58165869

Comment: @TARUNSHARMA Create a question and then will see.

Comment: Sir, I shared I link question is there.