# How can I calculate distance between multiple latitude and longitude?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to calculate total distance between each points both contains lat and long, these points are stored in local database, so the scenario is I want to calculate distance from point a to b & b to c & c to d and these points(lat and long) are stored into database using google place api [image]

All the points are fetched from database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)

Comment: Do you want driving distance, walking distance or straight line distance?

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate distance between 2 location points without using places api

```
    private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) 
                        * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
                        + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1))
                        * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
                        * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        return (dist);
    }

    private double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    private double rad2deg(double rad) {


return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

Comment: but I am storing the Lat and Long using places api it is required for app.

Comment: to calculate distance you dont need places api thats what i am saying

Comment: Yes you are right but according to diagram multiple points are stored in database these points are stored using places api now I want to create distance between each point

Comment: you have the list of points (location ) , first calculate distance between location 1 & location 2 , then location 2 and location 3 and add up the distance

Comment: I have dynamic points not static points points could be up to 20 could be 30

Comment: How can Convert it into Km ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the scope of this question. Do you need to take into account the curvature of earth? Or it is just 2 random points?

**If it's the first** : I can show you this link as i cannot help you out:

https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

**If it is the latter:**

Suppose 1 is latitude and 2 is longitude, so that a1 is latitude of point A.

[image: Calculating distance from 2 points]

Calculating 2 points in a plane is something like somethign like this:

Distance = `sqrt((a1−b1)+(a2−b2))`

So, to calculate for example distance from D to E is: `sqrt((e1-d1) + (e2-d2))`

Comment: I suppose you already have the coordinates stored somewhere in your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DistanceCalculator
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") + " Miles\n");
        System.out.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") + " Kilometers\n");
        System.out.println(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") + " Nautical Miles\n");
    }

    private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, String unit) {
        if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            double theta = lon1 - lon2;
            double dist = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat2)) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta));
            dist = Math.acos(dist);
            dist = Math.toDegrees(dist);
            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
            if (unit == "K") {
                dist = dist * 1.609344;
            } else if (unit == "N") {
                dist = dist * 0.8684;
            }
            return (dist);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] distanceWidth = new float[2];
Location.distanceBetween(
                startLatitude,
                startLongitude,
                endLatitude,
                endLongitude,
                distanceWidth);

//You will get float[] of results after Location.distanceBetween().

float distance = distanceHeight[0];
float distanceInKm = distance/1000;
```